# React Native tipsi-stripe - null is not an object (evaluating 'StripeModule.paymentRequestWithCardForm')

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

See the answer below to resolve this `tipsi-stripe` issue with React Native.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error message by the following steps.

1. `npm uninstall tipsi-stripe`
2. `npm install --save tipsi-stripe`
3. `cd ios`
4. Open up the Podfile and add `pod 'Stripe', '~> 14.0.0'` (if it isn't already in the Podfile), beneath the target keyword.
5. `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your above answer and it still gives the same error, null is not an object. I've tried using yarn add, also using your method of npm install --save tipsi-stripe. Also including a specific Stripe version in podfile. And pod installing.

Honestly, it occurred so consistently that I'm currently working on react-native-paypal. But I would like to use this method if it's at all possible. I also noticed the npm package says 'failing' currently, not sure if that has something to do with it. I followed your exact steps though.

EDIT: After all the configuration for PayPal/Braintree, at the very end with testing, I'm met with the exact same error: null is not an object. Looks like I'm back on Stripe for simplicity's sake, but this is terrible haha.

Comment: Are you using expo or have you ejected your expo environment to the bare workflow?

Comment: No, I don't use Expo. Thanks though

Comment: I think I need to add a bridge to xcode, that's where I'm at now in troubleshooting.